# Is there a way that we can use attribute selectors in Material-UI using makeStyles?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to extract all the div's having some specific Mui classenames say access-MuiPickersCalendarHeader-switchHeader,access-MuiPickersDay-day etc. Here the actual class names are
MuiPickersCalendarHeader-switchHeader,MuiPickersDay-day as per Material-ui. As I am seeding my components using StylesProvider it is adding **access** infront of the classes as prefix.
Is there anyway that i can fetch all the div's whose class names includes "MuiPickersDay-day","MuiPickersCalendarHeader-switchHeader" and style them using makeStyles in material-ui?

For Example:
Component 1 is having some elements with classnames : ***aboutpage-MuiPickersDay-day***
Component 2 is having some elements with classnames : ***homepage-MuiPickersDay-day***

Create a makeStyles where i can style both of the component's elements whose classname includes
**'MuiPickersDay-day'**

I have tried using attribute selectors in makeStyles but i am not able to do that. It is not allowing me to use that approach
For eample:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => createStyles({
               div[class^='MuiPickersDay-day]:{backgroundColor:'black'}
});
```

Comment: I suggest that you write an [answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so that it is listed (and can be found) as "answered".

Comment: @kca thanks for the suggestion. Posted the answer

Answer (score 2):

**Solution Found**:

In createStyles object do this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => createStyles({
               '*':{
                     '& [class*="MuiPickersDay-day"]':{
                               backgroundColor:'black'
                        }
} });
```

In this way not only can you just target div rather you can apply styles for all the elements which consist of 'MuiPickersDay-day' class. if you want you can also give multiple class names like: [class*="MuiPaper-root"][class*="MuiPopover-paper"][class*="MuiPaper-rounded"]

Happy Coding!!